# Implement trait for multiple Fn types

Tags: rust

I have a trait called `Describer` which has a function that accepts an array of bytes and returns a list of strings. For the sake of simplifying the codes, I want to accept both `Fn(&[u8]) -> Vec<String>` and `Fn(&[u8]) -> String` as a `Describer`.

So, here is what I have done:

```rust
trait Describer {
    fn get_parts(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<String>;
}

impl Describer for dyn Fn(&[u8]) -> Vec<String> {
    fn get_parts(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<String> {
        self(data)
    }
}

impl Describer for dyn Fn(&[u8]) -> String {
    fn get_parts(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<String> {
        vec![self(data)]
    }
}
```

But if I use a closure (or a function pointer) in place of a `Describer`, the compiler complains that the trait bounds are not satisfied. For example:

```rust
let x: Box<dyn Describer> = Box::new(|data: &[u8]| String::from("x"));
let y: Box<dyn Describer> = Box::new(|data: &[u8]| vec![String::from("y")]);
```

```
the trait bound `[closure@main.rs:223:38: 223:51]: Describer` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `Describer`:
  (dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r [u8]) -> String + 'static)
  (dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r [u8]) -> Vec<String> + 'static)
required for the cast from `[closure@main.rs:223:38: 223:51]` to the object type `dyn Describer
```

However, if I implement the trait for a generic that implements the closure type, it will work but then not possible to have both of the closure types because of the conflicting implementation error.

```rust
impl<F: Fn(&[u8]) -> Vec<String>> Describer for F {
    fn get_parts(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<String> {
        self(data)
    }
}

// Not working
impl<F: Fn(&[u8]) -> String> Describer for F {
    fn get_parts(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<String> {
        self(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trait that both `Vec<String>` and `String` impl and convert them to `Vec<String>`, then impl `Describer` for functions with return type implementing this trait:

```rust
trait DescriberResult {
    fn convert(self) -> Vec<String>;
}

impl DescriberResult for Vec<String> {
    fn convert(self) -> Vec<String> { self }
}

impl DescriberResult for String {
    fn convert(self) -> Vec<String> { vec![self] }
}

impl<R: DescriberResult, F: Fn(&[u8]) -> R> Describer for F {
    fn get_parts(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<String> {
        self(data).convert()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best recommendation, but I am curious why OP's attempt failed. I initially thought that Rust was simply unwilling to make the double jump from "made-up closure type" to `dyn Fn` and then to `dyn Describer` in one go, but I can't get it to compile even if I ascribe each step of that process explicitly.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo For multiple reasons: first, the code in the OP is actually `&str`, not `String`. Second, even with `String` it fails because `dyn Fn` cannot be converted to `dyn Describer`.  It works if you make `Box<dyn Fn(&[u8]) -> String>` and pass it to a function taking `Box<impl Describer>`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo You can't have a `&dyn TraitA` whose implementation is `dyn TraitB`, where would the vtable pointer go? Its always part of the reference type, but there is no reference for the inner `TraitB` only one for the outer trait (maybe if we had triple-fat pointers). You can constrain with it and use `impl` but it can't be doublely-dynamic.

Comment: I had never considered the double indirection required in the vtables. It's not something that's ever come up naturally in my own code, but it's interesting to know. Thanks, both of you!

Comment: Simple and beautiful. Also, thank you all for your helpful question and answers!

Comment: @ChayimFriedman While the answer itself is enough for me, I tried to test the two-step approach that you mentioned in your comment, but it didn't work. It would be great if you could add it to your answer.

Comment: @momvart I don't have time now, [but here's a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70ebd0b1a60ce28ea549fb2e530cda08).